# URL Rewriting in CodeIgniter using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am working on a project in which url Rewriting was done.
Here is the link of the old uri

```
http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/search/faisalabad/all-cats
```

But now in the new url I have changed it to

http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/pakistan/faisalabad/all-cats

what I want to do is to change the redirect all the url's whcih have  `http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/search/` search after job in them to the

```
http://www.mysite.pk/jobs/pakistan/
```

Here is my code of the route

```
$route["jobs/pakistan"]="vacancies/search";
```

If you have any other solution then .htaccess kindly share it.

Answer (score 0):

> .htaccess file use for remove index.php from base url following codes in .htaccess

```
      RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.     
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Rest your code are correct in route same

```
$route["jobs/pakistan"]="vacancies/search";
```

$route["Link You Want"]="Actual path to access";

Comment: then how should i do it if i cant not do it in .htaccess

Comment: you have to write in your route.php file<br/> $route["jobs/pakistan"]="vacancies/search";<br/> $route["yourNewLINK"]="ActualPathController-method";

Comment: i have tried your solution and add the code to routes files $route["jobs/search"]="vacancies/search"; but it is not working it is taking me to login page